# keyboard will not show up using play store

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-4

I have a Note 4 and when I use play store to shows the mic, if i move over to the left and touch the screen the keyboard only pops up for a second. I did a reset still the same, hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Google Voice typing. For this, goto *Settings>Language and Input*